# To build a special unary regular expression

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Say that there's a prime number P, 
And we can easily build an unary regular expression [E0]for every number that is divisible by P:
E0::= (aaaa...a)*,with p "a",

The question is, how do we build the opposite unary regular expression [E1], for every number that isn't divisible by P?

Do I need to build the E1 by listing all the number mod p=1,2, to p-1, or there can be a easier way to build it ?

Comment: @Evil Regular expressions have no accepting states.

Comment: Yes, RE does not have an accepting state, but such conversion RE -> DFA -> switch states -> minimize -> RE with purely mechanic transformation (almost virtual) will show the number of equivalence classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a "smart" way of following your approach:
$$
(a^p)^*a(\epsilon+a)^{p-1}
$$
Here $r^p$ is shortcut for $r$ concatenated $p$ times.

This regular expression has length $O(p)$. On the other hand, using the pumping lemma it is not hard to show that the minimal NFA for the language contains at least $p$ states, and this gives a lower bound of $\Omega(p)$ on the size of a regular expression for the language, since a regular expression can be translated to an NFA with only a constant multiplicative blow-up in size.